# How to remove the none error from the output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm creating a recursive function that creates n lines of asterisk. I do not have problems on writing code, but just am wondering why `None` appears in my output.

Here is my code:

```
def recursive_lines(n):
    for n in range(0,n):
        print ('*' + ('*'*n)) # Print asterisk
    
print(recursive_lines(5)) # Enter an integer here
```

And this is the result:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
None
```

I don't think I used any `int(print())` kind of statement here.. Then why does this error keep appearing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the purpose of the return statement? How is it different from printing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129285/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-return-statement-how-is-it-different-from-printing)

Comment: As an aside, your function isn't actually recursive because it doesn't call itself.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing out `recursive_lines(5)`, but inside the function, you are already printing the values. Simply remove the `print` that is around `recursive_lines(5)`

Answer (score 0):

The None is printing because you are using `print(recursive_lines(5))` even though your function is not returning anything. Remove the print statement while calling the function.

```
def recursive_lines(n):
    for n in range(0,n):
        print ('*' + ('*'*n)) 
    
recursive_lines(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function isn't returning anything. By default it'll return none. And if you don't want it to print `none` you can just not print recursive_lines(5).
If you add a return 0 statement it'll return 0 instead of none